# I am getting error while trying to run my flutter project

Tags: flutter

When I try to run my flutter project I get the error below. What could be the cause?                   ......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
/C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/carousel_slider-4.1.1/lib/carousel_slider.dart:268:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'padEnds'.
      padEnds: widget.options.padEnds,
      ^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/page_view.dart:664:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  PageView.builder({
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging_platform_interface-3.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:13:11: Error: Method not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
    Error.throwWithStackTrace(exception, stackTrace);
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging_platform_interface-3.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:16:9: Error: Method not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
  Error.throwWithStackTrace(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging_platform_interface-3.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:11:7: Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Never' doesn't allow null.
Never convertPlatformException(Object exception, StackTrace stackTrace) {
      ^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1035

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 41s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

These are my dependencies in my pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.3
#  google_fonts: ^2.1.0
  google_fonts: 2.2.0
  flutter_icons_nullsafty: ^1.0.0
  http: ^0.13.3
  cached_network_image: ^3.1.0
  encrypt: ^5.0.1
  flutter_svg: ^0.22.0
  qr_flutter: ^4.0.0
  clipboard: ^0.1.3
  share: ^2.0.4
  qr_code_scanner: ^0.5.2
  fluro: ^2.0.3
  url_launcher: ^6.0.10
  image_picker: ^0.8.4
  country_code_picker: ^2.0.2
  introduction_screen: ^2.1.0
  pin_code_fields: ^7.3.0
  provider: ^6.0.0
  hive: ^2.0.4
  hive_flutter: ^1.1.0
  flutter_secure_storage: ^4.2.1
  local_auth: ^1.1.7
  permission_handler: ^8.1.4+2
  fl_chart: ^0.40.0
  carousel_slider: ^4.0.0
  web3dart: ^2.3.1
  device_info_plus: ^2.1.0
  package_info_plus: ^1.3.0
  intl: ^0.17.0
  timeago: ^3.1.0
  razorpay_flutter: ^1.2.7
  flutter_paystack: ^1.0.5+1

  flutter_braintree: ^2.0.0+1
  loading_overlay: ^0.3.0
  lazy_load_scrollview: ^1.3.0
  shimmer: ^2.0.0
  in_app_review: ^2.0.3
  image_cropper: ^1.4.1
  ntp: ^2.0.0
  uuid: ^3.0.4
  cron: ^0.3.2
  dotted_border: ^2.0.0+1
  translator: ^0.1.7

  firebase_core: ^1.6.0

  firebase_messaging: ^10.0.9
  firebase_analytics: ^8.3.4
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^3.0.1
```

flutter doctor -v response

```
C:\Users\USER>flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel unknown, 2.2.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.264], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.2.0 at C:\src\flutter\flutter
    • Framework revision b22742018b (1 year ago), 2021-05-14 19:12:57 -0700
    • Engine revision a9d88a4d18
    • Dart version 2.13.0

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\USER\Documents\Sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 30.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\USER\Documents\Sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+7-b1504.28-7817840)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+7-b1504.28-7817840)

[√] VS Code (version 1.67.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.23.0

[√] Connected device (2 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 6.0 (API 23) (emulator)
    • Chrome (web)                       • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 100.0.4896.127

• No issues found!
```

Comment: can you try a `flutter clean` and then build again?

Comment: Please update the post with a `flutter doctor -v` response.

Comment: @Bruno J. I have update the post with flutter doctor -v response

Comment: @Ivo Beckers I have tried flutter clean, I am still getting same error

Comment: you need to show code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a too old flutter version. You are using version `2.2.0`

`padEnds` only became exposed in version `2.5.0` as you can see here:

https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/release-notes/release-notes-2.5.0

> 78558 Expose padEnds on PageView widget

You need to upgrade your flutter. You can do that by writing

```
flutter upgrade
```

though it says in your flutter doctor that you are on an unknown channel so maybe you need to do

```
flutter channel stable
```

first

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that some dependencies are using deprecated methods (which are removed in the newer Flutter version).

Try the following commands (WARNING: you will most likely have to update your codebase after this, and your packages as well.)

1. Update Flutter - `flutter upgrade`
2. Get dependencies - `flutter pub get`
3. Update dependencies `flutter pub upgrade`
4. Re-fetch dependencies - `flutter pub get`
5. Update your code to the newest version.
6. Rebuild

Comment: I did flutter upgrade before, but some of my packages like the qr_code_scanner package was giving me error so I had to downgrade my flutter version.

Comment: Try doing `flutter upgrade 2.5.0`